# Logging with AOP in .net

Tags: c#, logging, aop

I'm tired of using Logger.Log("MyMethod") at the beginning of each function in my c# application and started to look at how AOP can help me.

Basically what I want is to log entering to every method (public and private).
There are a lot of talks about this around the internet, but I hadn't found any specific library, with help of which I'll be able to just prefix my method with [Log] attribute and that's it.

There's [Log4PostSharp](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp) which seems to be perfect, but only works with PostSharp 1.5 which isn't available at the moment.

Are there some similar to Log4PostSharp things?

Thanks for help

Comment: can't you just download the source and compile it yourself against newest version of PostSharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2 is available.
http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/downloads/list

Comment: compiled for .net 3.5 unfortunately.. i need it for .net 2.0. Though, I'll try to compile it myself, thanks :)