# Finding out parameter values of method call (static class which I do not own).

Tags: c#, interceptor

is it possible to get the parameter values of a function call in a static class? I do not own the Class, so I cannot edit the code. And overriding does not work on static classes.
However, I can call the function with my own parameters without a problem.

During run time the program will call the function with specific parameters which I need to find out.

I read that it is possible with an interceptor but there are different ways how to do so.
Which one should I choose to solve this?

I would be very thankful for a small example or tutorial :)

Comment: The 'values' are whatever you call it with.

Comment: Do you control the program calling the method? Can you run it in debug mode and put a breakpoint in?

Comment: What do you want to be able to do with those values?

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is not my code and it is already compiled, the program allows & loads "plugins" (your own code). I did already override some methods but the other part is static.

Comment: @Chris Sadly no, its already compiled

Comment: @PeterRitchie The wanted parameter is a location object(x,y,z). And when the method gets called during run time (not by me), I just want to save the value. The method does not need to get stopped.

Comment: You can write your own code and override a function called pulse(), there you can put function calls or whatever you want in it. Pulse() get called multiple times per second. The function with the desired parameter value gets also called with every pulse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is typically called aspect-oriented interception (or AOP interception).  In particular, what it sounds like you want to do is aspect-oriented logging.  more information about that can be found at [Logging with AOP in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665454/logging-with-aop-in-net)

There's limits to what you can do with interception depending on your deployment scenarios (e.g. if you're deploying to a least privilege environment, it may not work).  You generally use a framework for AOP and interception.  One such framework is PostSharp.

Fortunately there are some good  Pluralsight courses on AOP and PostSharp:
http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents/aop